# Mosquitto MQTT TLS client from LAN refused

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, mqtt, mosquitto, tls1.3

I'm trying to setup a a secure MQTT broker with mosquitto and TLS, so that it accepts clients from LAN. When connecting from the same host as broker the problem doesn't occur,
however whatever I try to connect from the remote client the outcome is always the error below:

client side:

```bash
~/client# mosquitto_sub -t \$SYS/broker/bytes/\# -v --cafile ../ca/ca.crt --cert client.crt --key client.key -h remote_hostname
Error: A TLS error occurred.
```

broker side:

```bash
$ sudo mosquitto -v -c /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/very_basic.conf 
1687517830: mosquitto version 2.0.11 starting
1687517830: Config loaded from /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/very_basic.conf.
1687517830: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 8883.
1687517830: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 8883.
1687517830: mosquitto version 2.0.11 running
1687517831: New connection from 192.168.42.111:54214 on port 8883.
1687517831: OpenSSL Error[0]: error:0A000412:SSL routines::sslv3 alert bad certificate
1687517831: Client <unknown> disconnected: Protocol error.
```

I'm not sure why the `alert bad certificate` occurs. The ca, broker and client certificates are generated as below:

```bash
# ca
openssl req -newkey rsa:4096 -x509 -days 365 -extensions v3_ca -keyout ca.key -out ca.crt -nodes -sha256 -subj "/CN=ca.com"

# broker
openssl genrsa -out broker.key 2048 && openssl req -out broker.csr -key broker.key -new -subj "/CN=${HOSTNAME}"
openssl x509 -req -in client.csr -CA ../ca/ca.crt -CAkey ../ca/ca.key -CAcreateserial -out client.crt -days 100

# client
openssl genrsa -out client.key 2048 && openssl req -out client.csr -key client.key -new -subj "/CN=${HOSTNAME}"
openssl x509 -req -in client.csr -CA ../ca/ca.crt -CAkey ../ca/ca.key -CAcreateserial -out client.crt -days 100
```

the filesystem tree is as below:

```
.
├── broker
│   ├── broker.crt
│   ├── broker.csr
│   └── broker.key
├── ca
│   ├── ca.crt
│   └── ca.key
└── client
    ├── client.crt
    ├── client.csr
    └── client.key
```

The *ca.crt* and *broker.crt*, *broker.key* are copied to `/etc/mosquitto/ca_certificates` and `/etc/mosquitto/certs` of broker device, broker fiels are owned by user `mosquitto`. The client files and *ca.crt* are copied to a remote client device.

and finally the MQTT configuration `/etc/mosquitto/conf.d/very_basic.conf` is as below:

```
listener 8883
require_certificate true
use_identity_as_username true

cafile /etc/mosquitto/ca_certificates/ca.crt
certfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/broker.crt
keyfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/broker.key
```

`/etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf` remains as default:

```
# Place your local configuration in /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/
#
# A full description of the configuration file is at
# /usr/share/doc/mosquitto/examples/mosquitto.conf.example

pid_file /run/mosquitto/mosquitto.pid

persistence true
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/

log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log

include_dir /etc/mosquitto/conf.d
```

What could I be doing wrong?

EDIT:

as asked by @hardillb, below is the OpenSSL version on the broker and output on the remote client with the `-d` option added:

```bash
$ openssl version
OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022 (Library: OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022)
```

```bash
~/client# mosquitto_sub -t \$SYS/broker/bytes/\# -v --cafile ../ca/ca.crt --cert client.crt --key client.key -h remote_hostname -d
Client null sending CONNECT
OpenSSL Error[0]: error:0A000086:SSL routines::certificate verify failed
Error: A TLS error occurred.
```

Comment: What are the differences between the 2 systems? e.g. OS/library versions, also do you get any more information if you add `-d` to the client cmd line

Comment: The broker system is currently a kubuntu linux 22.04, the client is an embedded linux based on the OpenSTLinux distribution made by ST Microelectronics.

Comment: Check openssl versions

Comment: Okay, openssl version on the broker is `OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022 (Library: OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022)`
and the output of client with the `-d` option is as below, I'll add both of these to the original post:
`Client null sending CONNECT
OpenSSL Error[0]: error:0A000086:SSL routines::certificate verify failed
Error: A TLS error occurred.`

Comment: Does the CN of the broker cert actually match the hostname you are using to connect from the remote machine?

Comment: yes, I'm certain the broker CN matches it's hostname. To make sure the broker is reachable by it's hostname from the client I put `remote_hostname 192.168.42.1` in the `/etc/hostnames` of the client device, where `remote_hostname` is the hostname of the broker.

Comment: Any more ideas? Still haven't resolved the problem.

Comment: try running `openssl s_client --verifyCAfile ../ca/ca.crt -connect remote_host:8883` on the client machine, this should give a very verbose output from openssl checking that the connection can be setup and that the broker cert was signed by the provided CA cert

Comment: great tip! It seems that the certificate "is not yet valid" as it was issued by a machine that knows the current date, however later used by a client machine, which is still stuck in 2022. I'll work on it more tomorrow. Thank you!

Comment: You always need an accurate clock to use TLS properly, I suggest you setup ntp on the client device.